# Easy way to implement "swipe to preview" -- is this PageViewController?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I've noticed on a few apps, the app (prior to login) begins with a tutorial screen. I know that UIPageViewController can be used to build a tutorial screen, but the format of these other app screens' seem to have a much more aesthetically pleasing "swipe to preview" functionality built in. They all look similar to this:

[image: phone screen with swipe to preview]

Is this done with a specific view controller that I'm not seeing? Or is it a Page View Controller embedded in a container in another view controller? I feel as though there's a simple way of doing this that I'm not seeing.

Comment: maybe they are using some libraries...

Comment: You could just use a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to true. Then in the `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` delegate method, you update your `UIPageControl`

Comment: [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820939/setting-up-uiscrollview-to-swipe-between-3-view-controllers/19821086#19821086)